# Flask to pass value between view functions

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I would like to pass a value from one view function to another. I tries using session for this as follows:

```
@app.route('/home', methods=['GET','POST'])

def home():
 if request.form.get('data'):
    
    data1=request.form.get('data')
    session['a'] = data1
    return render_template('home.html')


@app.route('/section', methods=['GET','POST'])

def section():
 a = session.get('a')
 return render_template('section.html')
```

This works fine for me. But I see a delay in time for displaying a new value after each submission of the form.

Is there any other option for doing this or how can this be improved?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You aren't showing any code that would cause the new value to be shown.

Comment: Sorry, i have now updated my post. The new value comes from form submission.

Answer (score 1):

You could also pass the argument to the second route via redirect, like this

```
@app.route('/home', methods=['GET','POST'])

def home():
 if request.form.get('data'):
    
    data1=request.form.get('data')
    return redirect(url_for('section', value=data1))


@app.route('/section/<value>', methods=['GET','POST'])
def section(value):
 print(f'Received {value=}!')
 return render_template('section.html')
```

Comment: Thanks xArbisRox! I thought about this but was looking for an option other than redirect. I have a lot of analysis that is performed on this page. I was wondering if this will refresh the page. I am not sure. Anyway, I will give it a try! Thank you!